# Can I use constraints with any element?

Tags: javafx, constraints, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I apologize for perhaps lame question but I'm new to JavaFX and after reading 4 tutorials I can't find clear information how constraints work.

Can I set constraints to any control? Here is what I'm trying to achieve. I have `VBox` with `ButtonBar` of fixed height and I want second control to fill remaining area as I resize `VBox`.

[image]

```
<AnchorPane id="main-pane" style="-fx-border-color: #ADFF2F;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <ButtonBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <buttons>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
              </buttons>
            </ButtonBar>
            <AnchorPane id="inner-pane" style="-fx-border-color: #FF0000;">
               <children>
                  <ColorPicker prefHeight="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Interestingly enough `inner-pane` widens as I resize the window but botton edge does not. How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are using `SceneBuilder`, you can do the following :

- Remove the anchorpane and make ColorPicker a child of `VBox`. Since [`anchorpane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) is not the perfect layout for what you are trying to achieve. It allows the edges of child nodes to be anchored to an offset from the anchor pane's edges, but has no property to enforce their growth when the same happens to it.
- In the `ColorPicker` *Layout properties* set `VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"` and Max Height and Max Width as `MAX_VALUE`.

**FXML** (Incase you don't use SB)

```
<AnchorPane id="main-pane" style="-fx-border-color: #ADFF2F;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <ButtonBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <buttons>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
              </buttons>
            </ButtonBar>
            <ColorPicker prefHeight="200.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Oh so constraints of a parent are visible in properties pane of children. That's unexpected :) Thanks a lot !